# Webdrivermanager for new Chrome version

Tags: java, selenium, maven

How to get the updated chrome version i.e 94 .0.46  for my Maven dependency? In my Eclipse version 92 is still working. Even though I am changing webdrivermanager it shows sessionNotCreated ERROR
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is latest we have :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

put it on your `pom.xml` and take the latest, should help you past the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for use the perticular version,

**Java**  :

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("92.0.4515.43").setup();
webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
```